# Supabase policy for only one column

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js, supabase-py, supabase-flutter

I have a table with articles and there is column "likes" and I need to allow to anyone (public) to INSERT into this column only "likes". How can I write SQL code for this policy that allow users to insert only into specific column? Is it possible?